# Can't convert data.frame into numeric in R

Tags: r, dataframe, numeric

I'm working with a dataframe called creditcard in R and I wanted to compute correlation of the variable Debt from that same dataframe. However, and I don't know why, it gives me an error message saying Debt has to be numeric:

Error in cor(Debt,Limit) : 'x' must be numeric

I tried converting it to a numeric variable with this code:

Debt=as.numeric(as.character(Debt))

It still doesn´t work. It becomes numeric, but has lost most of its previous 400 observations, which were reduced to just 13...

```
 > sapply(creditcard,class)
       ID    Income     Limit 
"integer" "numeric" "integer" 
   Rating     Cards       Age 
"integer" "integer" "integer" 
Education    Gender   Student 
"integer"  "factor"  "factor" 
  Married Ethnicity      Debt 
 "factor"  "factor" "integer"
```

Sample data:

```
  > dput(head(Debt))
c(NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_, NA_real_)
```

I've been working with the creditcard dataframe for 3 months now, and haven't had this problem until recently, as Debt mysteriously started behaving like a data.frame object instead of numeric. Any ideas how I might get my old numeric Debt back with all 400 observations? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Provide example data: `dput(head(Debt))`.

Comment: How can you compute a correlation of a single variable?

Comment: `cor(Debt,Limit)`? Why not `cor(my_df$Debt, my_df$Limit)` (or `with(my_df, cor(Debt, Limit))`, where `my_df` is your data frame containing credit card information. Do you use `attach()` somewhere? Please attach the return of  `sapply(my_df, class)`, or provide sample data, as already mentioned by @zx8754

Comment: Are you working with this https://rdrr.io/cran/ISLR/man/Credit.html ? Is `Debt` self-created? Or renamed (cp. `Balance`)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `cor` function can take different inputs. If you provide it a matrix or data.frame as single argument, it will give you a correlation matrix for all variables, however all variables then have to be numeric.

To get all correlations of numerical variables of the `creditcard` data.frame you could do `cor(creditcard[,sapply(credicard, is.numeric)])`.

Otherwise you can get the correlation between single columns of your data.frame by giving it two arguments, either as `cor(creditcard$Debt, creditcard$Limit)` or as `with(creditcard, cor(Debt, Limit))`.

The errors you are currently getting come from the fact that the variables you are calling are either inaccessible or the wrong type. If you call `cor(A, B)`, both A and B have to be in your current environment. If A and B are columns of a data.frame, they are not directly accessible, so you can either expose the columns of the data.frame using `with(creditcard, ...)` as shown above, or directly access the columns within the data.frame (`creditcard$A` or `creditcard[,"A"]` or `creditcard[["A"]]`).

Comment: That worked, but only for correlation. If I want to plot a corrplot of creditcard I face the same problem:
> library(corrplot)
> corrplot(creditcard)
Error in FUN(X[[i]], ...) : 
  only defined on a data frame with all numeric-alike variables

Comment: As I said you then have to make sure that you supply a data frame containing only numeric columns. Like with `cor(creditcard[,sapply(credicard, is.numeric)])` you can do `corrplot(creditcard[,sapply(credicard, is.numeric)])`

Answer (score 0):

It looks like my stated guess is right. As mentioned in a comment, based on the error message, I assume you are missing the `$`-operator to access variables (columns) from your data frame.

Another option, also mentioned in the comment, is using `with()` instead. Here an example based on the `Credit` data set from `{ISLR}` where I have renamed `Balance` to `Debt`.

```r
library(ISLR)
data(Credit)
names(Credit)
#>  [1] "ID"        "Income"    "Limit"     "Rating"    "Cards"     "Age"      
#>  [7] "Education" "Gender"    "Student"   "Married"   "Ethnicity" "Balance"
colnames(Credit)[ncol(Credit)] = "Debt"
with(Credit, cor(Limit, Debt))
#> [1] 0.8616973
```

<sup>Created on 2023-12-08 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>